# Giving me an error when I use prebuilt UI from Firebase for authentication in Xcode. No known class method for selector 'labelColor'

Tags: xcode, firebaseui

I am trying to use the prebuilt UI Firebase AUTH provides. When I build the project it gives me this error *"No known class method for selector 'labelColor'"*

Note: I have been able to connect to Firebase.

This is what the error looks like:
[Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnTJS.jpg)

This is what my podfile looks like: [Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYcwI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are running Xcode 11. I had the same issue after updating my FirebaseUI/... pods to 8.4.0 and after some searching issue in the Github repo that it requires Xcode update.